# how to set default location to open dialog path in html?

Tags: asp.net, .net, html

I have one input(type=file)button in my html page.When pressing the upload button,Open Dialog will appear and its points to desktop right now.But i want to set the default location for that open dialog path.For example, whenever upload button is pressed,the open dialog's default path will be "c:\myRoot".

Is there any way to do in Html?If it is not possible, then tell me a way to do it in asp page.

Thanks & Regards,
P.SARAVANAN

Comment: Not really - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/818111/control-the-working-directory-for-input-type-file. Also, remember, browser clients will have different file systems; C:\ will mean nothing to an Apple or Linux user.

Comment: We considering only for windows platform

Comment: Doesn't change it I'm afraid - although there are some ideas in the linked question I've added.