# How to fix the initial uri of a browse button

Tags: javascript, html, css, jsp, servlets

I want to create a browse  button so i found this code : and it works fine

```
<form action="http://www.cs.tut.fi/cgi-bin/run/~jkorpela/echo.cgi"
enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
<p>
Type some text (if you like):<br>
<input type="text" name="textline" size="30">
</p>
<p>
Please specify a Test , or a set of tests:<br>
<input type="file" name="datafile" size="40" >
</p>
<div>
<input type="submit" value="Execute Test">

</div>
</form>
```

But in my case the browse functionality should begin from a specific URI (C:\software\apache-tomcat-7\apache-tomcat-7.0.28\wtpwebapps\WebTestAutomatisation\WEB-INF\classes\functional)

So i want to fix the initial uri 
I make a search in the input tag attributes but i didn't find anything useful

Comment: I need some more clarification. What you exactly want to do.

Comment: @ArunJain i don't want the user of this browse button to search the uri i just want him to import the file located in the fixed uri this file is a java class . thank you

Answer (score 1):

You want to change the default path when the user click on "browse" ?

I think it is not possible to change the default path of an input type files because it can be a big security hole...

Comment: i want to fix the path to this uri C:\software\apache-tomcat-7\apache-tomcat-7.0.28\wtpwebapps\WebTestAutomatisation\WEB-INF\classes\functional

Comment: Ih you find a solution, i want to know^^

Answer (score 1):

I don't think what you are trying to do is possible. Like @ClementAndraud pointed out, this can be a big security hole if it is allowed. meanwhile you can check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/818111/control-the-working-directory-for-input-type-file) for further clarification.