# How to pre-specify a download location for a dynamically generated file?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, http, jakarta-ee

In our web application, I'd like for a user to be able to specify a location on his local computer where a CSV file (generated by JSP) will be put.  I've seen several posts that show how a dynamically generated file can be saved to a location upon receiving a response (e.g., [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/260519)).  Is there a way for the user to specify the local location when making the request?

I am constrained to using IE7 or IE9 as our supported browsers.  We are also using a Java EE stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe this can be done in pure HTML/Javascript (but perhaps through an applet).

First of all, (in general, but not in your case) the client machine is not guaranteed to be running a specified OS, so the server would not be certain that it's suggested location is valid.

Second, as specified in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/818111/control-the-working-directory-for-input-type-file), it is a potential security issue:

> You cannot control the contents of a file input using JavaScript for security reasons. Otherwise, you could create a hidden form with a file input field, set it to a path, and submit the form with JavaScript in order to upload the file to your server without the user knowledge.

So unfortunately, in your case it seems like neither of these two are truly a concern, however, they are potential reasons that the functionality does not exist.