# How to open a file browser with default directory in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to open a file browser in JavaScript and set a default directory to this file browser.
For example, I will like to set the default directory to "C:\My Documents".

How to set a default directory?
It's better to use `<input type="file"/>`, other controls are ok too.

Comment: possible duplicate of [control the working directory for <input type="file">?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/818111/control-the-working-directory-for-input-type-file)

Comment: I don't think it is possible. How users with a non-windows OS would use it? And think about the security risk of accessing user's filesystem.

Comment: I'm currently not sure if it is possible to define a certain location in `html5` like `images`, `documents` or `movies` as default. But even if it is now possible, defining a whole path like `C:\My Documents` (i hope it is not possible) would not make much sens, because the path could change from system to system.

Comment: My requirement is not limit to <input type="file"/>, others are fine for me if it doesn't support to specify default directory. It's fine if can set images, documents or movies (specific folders) as default.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is impossible, as it is a security risk to let website code set any value on the machine.

Also, you can never be sure that directory exists.
What if I'm on a Mac? My stuff are in `~/Pictures`. What if I installed Windows on `D:\`?

Comment: If you are developing enterprise software that runs on a single platform you can pretty well be 100% sure a directory exists.

Comment: @MichaelPaccione This is Untrue. I just ran into an issue that locks Chrome up completely for 200+ seconds when an NFS share is not available. This happens because my resource is behind a VPN and if the PWD is within this resource and the user is not connected to the network or the VPN it looks like their chrome crashed. I came here to see if this was exploitable and fortunately it's not!

Answer (score -5):

From http://www.pcreview.co.uk/threads/automatically-put-a-default-filename-in-input-type-file-value.2192852/

`<input type="file" value="YourDefaultPathAndFilename.AndExtension">`

Comment: I really would like to it work... I'm sure about the file location but I really dont believe this will work due security reasons; but if you can, I would love to see a working example for javaScript