# HTML/javascript: In an input type="file", is it possible to set a default directory?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i am trying to set a default directory in  a browse of an `INPUT type="file"`.

Is it possible to do it using jquery, javascript or html5 or html?

Comment: David I think it's impossible please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17420595/how-to-open-a-file-browser-with-default-directory-in-javascript

Comment: How would you know this default directory considering that all users may have different OS, disk names, etc etc ?

Comment: the short answer is no. you don't have access to read the file system in js. plus, what would you do if the dir you were looking for didn't exist?

Comment: I should mention Windows only