# Suggesting directory in file input html element

Tags: html, google-chrome, input, webkit

When a user clicks a input value with type = file they are prompted with a mini-explorer type window from which they can select a file.  Is there anyway to control what directory they are shown first?

Obviously doing so fruitfully would require knowledge of the user’s file system.  But for my use case I do know the file system of my users.

(For what its worth, i’m webkitdirectory function to ask a user to select a directory, and I would like to start by suggesting a default that makes sense for my use case).

Comment: You can't do this due to some security reasons.

Comment: Explain the security reasons...

Comment: You can refer this link.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17420595/how-to-open-a-file-browser-with-default-directory-in-javascript