# How can I send file data with post request with browsing from file loaction, just set file loaction by default

Tags: ajax, rest, web-services, post, form-data

How can I send file data with post request without browsing from file loaction, just set file loaction by default.

```
<form id="data_post" > 　 　 　 　  
<input type="file" name="file" value='C:/file/new.pdf'>    　  
<input type="text" name="Param">　  
</form>
```

but this not getting the file, when going to send it through rest post request.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you can set a default file location.
Check this: [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17420595/how-to-open-a-file-browser-with-default-directory-in-javascript)