# How to write in case of always selecting the same directory by <input type = "file" in HTML arranged file in Windows local

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, batch-file, puppeteer

HTML files are placed locally on Windows, as I only have to be able to operate them.
It's painful to choose the same folder every time in the browser.
I want to automate the task of just selecting a folder in the browser.

HTML

```
<input type="file" multiple accept="image/*" webkitdirectory>
```

JavaScript

```
document.querySelector('input[type="file"]').onchange = function() {
```

Always choose the Windows directory

```
C:\hoge
```

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17420595/how-to-open-a-file-browser-with-default-directory-in-javascript) answer your question? Or do you mean select it through puppeteer?

Comment: If I use  puppeteer, can I do what I want to do?

Comment: Sorry, I can't answer that. My first instinct was something like that question I linked, but I only saw the puppeteer tag later (and I don't have experience with that)