# Open folder selection in playframework

Tags: java, html, playframework

I'm using playframework in java.

I want to **show pop-up for select folder path** to save file when user click button on **html page**.

Please help me.
Thanks for all.

Comment: That's a HTML issue, something like `<input type="file">`??

Comment: Thanks, but i want to select folder, not the file, i want to get the folder path on client.

Comment: I guess you'll have to send the 'valid' file tree along with your template or maybe fetch it with an ajax call, so you will be able to display the file tree for the user and let him pick the folder he likes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pre-selecting folder path on the client machine its not possible with standard html input element. Have a look into that question: [control the working directory for <input type="file">?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/818111/control-the-working-directory-for-input-type-file).

You can try to use a separate java applet tho, like the one here: http://jupload.sourceforge.net/