# Set default directory to browse for file upload

Tags: file, upload, directory

I have a form that allows the user to upload a file but I want to know how to set the default browse directory. So when the user clicks browse it opens to the directory I've specified not the desktop or C drive. Does anybody know how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

This question reminds me of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/818111/control-the-working-directory-for-input-type-file). With HTML and Javscript, I do not believe it is possible.