# Open a specific file using Browse button

Tags: javascript, php, html

Is it possible to "make" the Browse button to open the file that I have written in the textbox by default? Below is my code. The value inside the textbox is Desktop by default. How can I make Browse button to open the Desktop when it is pressed?

```
Data Save Directory:<input name="datasaveaddress" type="text" value="Desktop"> <input name="datasavedir" type="file" id="fileUpload" value="Browse">
```

Comment: I'm a tad confused, do you mean you want the value from your text field, to be the copied over to the file input so that it "automatically" selects that file?

Comment: whats a "Browse" button?

Comment: One day, i will die sure after seeing this type of requirements.

Comment: I see what you mean now. This cannot be done. You need to understand that users will use different browsers and operating systems such as OSX which may vary in directories.

Comment: Indeed. Many machines don't even have a "desktop".

Comment: @Epodax yes. But the value in the textbox (the address) is a default value and pre-set.

Comment: @NanaPartykar I have seen a tutorial on Arduino and the instructor opened the file with the address written in the textbox. So it is doable.Don't be so dramatic :)

Comment: @CodeGodie I only need to do this on my Ubuntu and my own directories. In that case would you be able to help me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [control the working directory for <input type="file">?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/818111/control-the-working-directory-for-input-type-file)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do. You can use text box and button. But make sure you are using fileupload widget hidden in your DOM. On click of normal button, update file upload widget and text box.