# GWT Upload: How to Open Browser in a specific folder

Tags: java, gwt, upload, java-web-start

Is there some way to setup a GWT UpLoad to start browsing from a specific folder ?

To have the windows browser work from a specific folder ?

or is that impossible in which case you would have to use some other way...

Could JAVA WEB START as shown here be limited or start from a specific folder ?

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/JWSFileChooserDemoProject/src/components/JWSFileChooserDemo.java

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to change the default directory for uploads in a browser from a web page. That's a security issue - see commentary [control the working directory for <input type=“file”>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/818111/control-the-working-directory-for-input-type-file).

Given permission to the local machine, Java applets/applications deployed JWS would have the ability - additionally, ActiveX controls could also work for you if you're focusing on Windows.