# Detect automatically a specific file with specific extension in a given folder in Svelte

Tags: file, svelte

Recently I coded this in svelte:

```
<script>
    let files = [];
    
    function contentArray(ev){
            let newlySelected = [...ev.target.files].filter(f => !files.some(ff => ff.file.name === f.name));
            //console.log(newlySelected.length);
            files = [...files, ...newlySelected.map(file => ({file, textPromise: file.text()}))];
    }
</script>
    
    <input type='file' multiple on:change={contentArray} accept=".txt">
    {#each files as {file, textPromise} (file.name)}
            <p>The imported file is: {file.name}</p>
            {#await textPromise then text}
            <pre>{text}</pre>
            {:catch}
            <div>error</div>
            {/await}
    {/each}
```

As you can see, if I want to import a *.txt* file I must manually import it. Is there a method to automatically import those *.txt* files only giving a folder to the program? The folder can be programmatically only one (for example I write in the code to open always the folder *example* which is EVER in the same file path, no worry if I change PC or whatsoever.)
I know that my explanation can be a little confusing but I am not an English speaker, so forgive me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [control the working directory for <input type="file">?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/818111/control-the-working-directory-for-input-type-file)

Comment: I tried some of the Solutions, but I finally decided to posticipate this problem, otherwise i can't go on with my project... Anyway, thanks for the reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For security reasons, with JS you can't read an entire folder, but I think you can at least set a default path for the file selector.